# Cron http request to cloud function - look into database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use cron to trigger my cloud function in order to look at my database every couple hours. I can trigger the function automatically, but the output is not what I was expecting. I'm just a tad bit confused on why I am not able to retrieve anything from the database, meaning I can't log out my console.log("refund"). I currently have 1 document in the request collection and has 1 file with the replied field that satisfies replied == false. So I'm just confused on how to go about this correctly since I believe it should've logged that once?

```
exports.daily_job = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const key = req.query.key;

    // Exit if the keys don't match.
    if (!secureCompare(key, functions.config().cron.key)) {
    console.log('The key provided in the request does not match the key set in the environment. Check that', key,
        'matches the cron.key attribute in `firebase env:get`');
    res.status(403).send('Security key does not match. Make sure your "key" URL query parameter matches the ' +
        'cron.key environment variable.');
    return null;
    }

    let db = admin.firestore()
    let request = db.collection('request')
        .where('replied', '==', false)
            .get().then(function(querySnapshot){
                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                   console.log("refunded")
                })
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Error getting documents: ', error)
                res.send('error');
            })

    res.send('finished refund');
    return null;
});
```

Comment: I don't see a "need refund" log line.

Comment: sorry just changed it                             console.log("refunded")

Comment: So something weird happened, so it logged out, Function execution took 2916 ms, finished with status code: 200, then it logged out "refunded"

Comment: So it came after the execution? I mean I guess if it's async but I didn't make it await..

Comment: It maybe never called back at all.  Cloud Functions will shut everything down after the response is sent.

Comment: You might want to watch my series on dealing with promises in Cloud Functions.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM&index=2

Comment: Ok I'll take a look at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not waiting on the promise returned by `get()`, which is asynchronous.  As your code is now, the entire function sends a response "finished refund" immediately after the query is made, before it has time to finish.  Once you send a response, the function is terminated.

You need to send the client response only after all the async work is complete in your function, which would be in **BOTH** your `then()` and `catch()` callbacks.

Comment: Right but if I did send a response back after the document has been "refunded" then it wouldn't be able to look at multiple? Watching the video xd

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "look at multiple".  Your code will do whatever you tell it to.  Don't sent the response until all work is done.